# How do I pull data from a mysql db with php and replace text in only selected table cells

Tags: php, html

In my code I am pulling two columns from a mysql db.  task1 table column is a boolean of 0 or 1, task1time is date/time.  What I am trying to do is convert the '0' to text 'Not Completed' and the '1' to text 'Completed'.  I have though about using text replace but only what it to affect selected table cells not all table cells

```
<?php
include("../lib/config.php");
$conn=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT * FROM role_one");
    mysqli_close($conn);

    while($column = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" . "task1" . "</th>";
        echo "<td>" . $column['task1'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" . "task1time" . "</th>";
        echo "<td>" . $column['task1time'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use a simple conditional statement to display different text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression:

```
        echo "<td>" . ($column['task1'] ? 'Completed' : 'Not Completed') . "</td>";
```

You could also change your SQL to return this instead of the raw value:

```
SELECT IF(task1, 'Completed', 'Not Completed') AS task1, task1time
FROM role1
```